# My api call ends up with Error: socket hang up, i am making and get call request with the axios using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making and google API call to get the address of the user with the help of the lat and long of the user, but when I am making a call of the API in the console it shows the correct data but in postman, it shows Error: socket hang up nothing is returned my code is as below

```
var getLocation = async function(req, res, next){
  let lat = req.query.lat;
  let lng = req.query.lng;

  data = await axios.get(`https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${lat},${lng}&key=mykey`)
  .then(function(response){
    if(response.status != 200){
      console.log("error has occured");
    }else{
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data),"data value")
      return JSON.stringify(response.data);
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err,"error")
  })
}
```

I am able to see the console data value as expected but in postman, it goes forever and after some time it throws me socket hang up
Any help would be much appreciated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is to send a response to the client by change

```
return JSON.stringify(response.data);
```

to be

```
res.send(response.data);
```

Comment: @Avinash jain keep in mind also to send object to contain proper error message in  exception cases